# client.get_guild(id).members throws AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord.py

So I'm implementing a discord bot for my server and what I'm trying to do is that the bot takes a file (called "counselors.txt") and it loops through all the members in the server and if they have a specific role then they get written in that file. But every time I try to implement this with the following code:

```
def extractAdmins():
    f = open("counselors.txt", "w")
    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id_num)
    for member in guild.members:
        for role in member.roles:
            if role == "admin" or role == "EstudianteOrientador":
                f.write(member.name + '\n')
    f.close()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/pyBot/bot.py", line 36, in <module>
    extractAdmins()
  File "/Users/bermed28/Desktop/pyBot/bot.py", line 20, in extractAdmins
    for member in guild.members:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'members'
```

I know that the AttributeError means that the Guild is null for some reason but I got the correct guild ID from my server so I don't know what's wrong. Any help?

Comment: What is your full code? You're probably trying to use `client.get_guild` before the bot has connected.

Comment: Adding onto what Benjin said, if what he said was the case, you can add `await client.wait_until_ready()` at the top of that function.

Comment: according to the documentation, get_guild will return None if the guild is not found. Make sure that you are using a valid guild ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill `guild_id_num` with the ID number. Be sure Developer Mode is on in settings, and right click your server and click "Copy ID" to get the ID.